# Find if a 2D list contains a value where the 3rd column is not relevant

Tags: python

I have a nested list where I'm only interested in the first 2 columns. (e.g., the first 2 columns are coordinates and the 3rd is the f value from A*, or some id for the coordinate, etc.)

```
a = [[1, 0, 2],
     [1, 1, 2],
     [1, 2, 2]]
```

I have an variable `b = [1, 0]` and I want to know if it is in the list, but I don't care what the 3rd column contains, so I am expecting the output to be `True`

Is it possible to do something like this without using loops? e.g.

```
if b in a[:][:2]:
    do stuff
```

Or maybe `[b[0], b[1], *] in a` where `*` is a wildcard? Neither of these work, they are just to try and explain what I'm getting at.

Obviously if I naïvely test `b in a` I get `False` because of the 3rd column.

Comment: This type multidimensional slice syntax/loopless notation is not available in base python. You can use a comprehension but, while that would make it a single line, it would not be loopless.

Comment: How about `any(b == row[:2] for row in a)`

Comment: @j1-lee Ah. Still a loop but perfect for keeping my code small, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using map to remove the third element for each list in `a` -

```
if b in list(map(lambda x: x[:2], a)):
    # do something
```